# Do the same GAE channel tokens work between tabs?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

Going by the GAE docs for the Channel API,

> Only one client at a time can connect to a channel using a given
>   Client ID, so an application cannot use a Client ID for fan-out. In
>   other words, it's not possible to create a central Client ID for
>   connections to multiple clients.

seems contradictory to

> Treat the token returned by create_channel() as a secret. If a
>   malicious application gains access to the token, it could listen to
>   messages sent along the channel you are using.

How can they both be true? But more importantly, I'm planning to create one channel for each logged in user in my app. Now if the user opens up a new tab with the app, can I use the same token again? The alternative of creating one channel per tab the user has open sounds quite odd, not to mention expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open more than one socket on a channel with the same token, results are undefined. Both sockets may receive messages, or neither, or just one. (actually we technically support two connections reliably, for cases where the user refreshes a page)

If you want to support multiple connections by the same user (in different tabs or different computers or whatever), you'll need to create a clientids per tab/browser instance/computer etc.

Comment: Are there any plans in the pipeline to either change this or release any token pooling utilities?

Comment: Yes, I am going to expand the number of concurrent connections allowed per token to support simple cases like "same user, multiple tabs". I'll add this to the release notes (and update this question) when it's ready, probably within a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thank you.. that information just saved me hours of work even if it comes out in the April release.

Comment: Not to nag, but any idea when this might come through?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's in production now.

Comment: @MoisheLettvin could you confirm that this is still in production? I just tried to reuse a token in a second tab (testing locally) and when a message was sent out only one of my channels/tabs received the message.

Comment: nm looks like it's a development thing. Once I deployed to production both windows received the message.

Comment: Is this behavior documented? If so, where? Also, @David Ward, did you file a issue report on this on the development server?